# How to add a node for failover in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I currently have single node for elasticsearch in a windows server. Can you please explain how to add one extra node for failover in different machine? I also wonder how two nodes can be kept identical using NEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you don't run a *failover* node, but run a cluster of nodes to provide High Availability.

A minimum topology of 3 master eligible nodes with [`minimum_master_nodes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#master-election) set to 2 and a sharding strategy that distributes primary and replica shards over nodes to provide data redundancy is the minimum viable topology I'd consider running in production.